# cmake find sqlite3 library on windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, cmake

I am having more trouble than I'd expect getting CMake to find the `sqlite3.dll` library on Windows 7 (64-bit if that matters). I have downloaded and placed the latest `sqlite3.dll` and `sqlite3.def` files to `C:\Windows\System32`. I am using the `FindSqlite3.cmake` module below:

```
IF( SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG )
    SET(SQLITE3_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF( SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG )

FIND_PATH( SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h )

FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES sqlite3 )

FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG NAMES sqlite3 sqlite3d HINTS /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/ C:/Windows/System32/ )

IF( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE OR SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR )
SET( SQLITE3_FOUND TRUE )
ENDIF( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE OR SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR )

IF( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE )
# if the generator supports configuration types then set
# optimized and debug libraries, or if the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE has a value
IF( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES OR CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
SET( SQLITE3_LIBRARIES optimized ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE} debug ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG} )
ELSE( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES OR CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
    # if there are no configuration types and CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE has no value
    # then just use the release libraries
SET( SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )
ENDIF( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES OR CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
ELSEIF( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE )
SET( SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )
ELSE( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE )
SET( SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG} )
ENDIF( SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE )

IF( SQLITE3_FOUND )
IF( NOT SQLITE3_FIND_QUIETLY )
MESSAGE( STATUS "Found Sqlite3 header file in ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR}")
MESSAGE( STATUS "Found Sqlite3 libraries: ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES}")
ENDIF( NOT SQLITE3_FIND_QUIETLY )
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
IF( SQLITE3_FIND_REQUIRED)
MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Sqlite3" )
ELSE( SQLITE3_FIND_REQUIRED)
MESSAGE( STATUS "Optional package Sqlite3 was not found" )
ENDIF( SQLITE3_FIND_REQUIRED)
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
```

This works fine on Linux, but not on Windows. I have spent a few hours now attempting small changes to other CMAKE variables with no luck. It seems like it should be straight forward getting CMake to find this `dll`. Could I get some help getting this to find the sqlite3 library on Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some issues here and also some weird Windows stuff!

First issue; when searching for a library on Windows with MSVC as the generator, CMake will always look for a ".lib" file - never a ".dll", even if you specify e.g. `sqlite3.dll` as the `NAMES` argument to `find_library`.  This is unfortunately not properly documented, in fact the docs for [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES) wrongly state:

> This specifies what suffixes to add to library names when the find_library command looks for libraries. On Windows systems this is typically .lib and .dll, meaning that when trying to find the foo library it will look for foo.dll etc.

You can easily check this; simply add

```
message("CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES:  ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")
```

to your CMakeLists.txt.  You should see output like:

> ```
> CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES:  .lib
> ```

[This thread](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/FindLibrary-only-looks-for-lib-under-Windows-td5532822.html) from the CMake mailing list further confirms this behaviour.  If you really need to find the dlls, you'll need to use the [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_file) command, e.g:

```
find_file(SQLITE3_DLL_DEBUG NAMES sqlite3d.dll PATHS ...)
```

---

The next issue is a minor one.  You should prefer `PATHS` to `HINTS` as the argument in `find_xxx` commands if it's a hard-coded guess.  From the docs for [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library):

> `3`. Search the paths specified by the `HINTS` option. These should be paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the `PATHS` option.

---

A slightly more serious issue is in the line:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY_DEBUG NAMES sqlite3 sqlite3d ...)
```

You should specify sqlite3d *first* then sqlite3 or sqlite3 will incorrectly be chosen as the Debug library if both are available.

---

And now the weirdness...

On a Windows x64 system, the `find_xxx` partially ignores the C:\Windows\System32 directory in favour of the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 one.

If you don't have the sqlite3.lib in C:\Windows\SysWOW64, then the `find_library` command will always fail, regardless of the `PATHS` argument.

However, if you *do* have C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sqlite3.lib, then any combination of `C:/Windows/SysWOW64` and/or `C:/Windows/System32` as the `PATHS` argument finds the library, but sets the full path to `C:/Windows/System32/sqlite3.lib` *even if C:/Windows/System32/sqlite3.lib doesn't exist*!  This is obviously useless if the library isn't there; a linker error will result.

There is some further reading again from the CMake mailing list [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-June/037312.html).

Having said that, if you're linking, you'll be using the .lib files, not the .dlls, and System32 & SysWOW64 aren't really the place for .lib files.

Comment: All this information was very helpful, thanks! The thing that fixed my issue was simply moving the `sqlite3.dll` and `sqlite3.def` files to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: Searching for a `.lib` looks normal... Even if you are expecting to use the `.dll`, you must link with a `.lib` ... and where you obtained the `.dll`, they have produced a `.lib` as well.

Comment: (sometimes the special .lib dedicated to .dll use is called .def)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find that **cmake** looks for **.lib. pls**.

please check the **cmake file** and **findSqlite.cmake** file inside **cmake folder** and check for **paths** it is looking for.

when I gave the full path to the "**dll**", it worked for me corresponding to the input variable mentioned in cmake file, and it might work for you too.

If your problem is not solved, notify me to edit the answer.