# CMake GUI: Specify library path for Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm compiling a CMake-based project (SOCI to be specific), that depends on SQLite. This being Windows, there are no standard paths for the project to look into, so it can't find SQLite, and I get this when configuring:

```
SQLite3 not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
See the documentation for SQLite3 or manually set these variables: 
SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR                      = SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
SQLITE3_LIBRARIES                        = SQLITE3_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

The SQLite lib and header files are at

```
c:\Workspace\SQLite\Release\SQLite.lib
c:\Workspace\SQLite\SQLite\sqlite3.h
c:\Workspace\SQLite\SQLite\sqlite3ext.h
```

Is it possible to tell CMake GUI where they are so it can find them?

**Note:** I'm talking about the GUI, not the command line. This is what the GUI looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try "Add Entry" button, it is equivalent to [-D option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#opt:-Dvar:typevalue) [image: how to add cache entry]

Comment: Hm, I tried it, but for some reason it still can't find SQLite, it says now `SQLITE3_LIBRARIES                        = c:\Workspace\SQLite\Release  SQLITE3_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`. Same for `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856445/cmake-find-sqlite3-library-on-windows

Comment: Maybe you have to specify SQLITE3_LIBRARY_RELEASE directory and not specify SQLITE3_LIBRARIES. Please check documentation for your FindSqlite3 module

Comment: OK thanks. Anyway, I'm marking your answer as correct because it is the correct way to set library paths in general.

Comment: I managed to 'force' it to work by copying the headers and lib to `C:\Windows\` eventually. CMake finds them there.