# Build Libevent with OpenSSL

Tags: windows, cmake, openssl, libevent

Tell me please, i am trying to build Libevent for Windows using Cmake GUI, I select the libevent folder and click - configure. But, cmake reports an error:

> Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in
> the   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:
> OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found   version "1.1.1i")

Let me ask you two questions:

- I understand that I have to show the Cmake the path to OpenSSL.
  I found a similar question: [CMake not able to find OpenSSL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl-library)

Where it says what is needed:

> set the variables below:
>
> OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=D:/softwares/visualStudio/openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32
> OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=D:/softwares/visualStudio/openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32/include
> OPENSSL_LIBRARIES=D:/softwares/visualStudio/openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32/lib

But I just can't figure out how to do this in CMake GUI.

- and i don't understand why the error says about openssl version 1.1.1i. Why exactly - "1.1.1i" ?

Comment: Found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476943/cmake-gui-specify-library-path-for-windows

Comment: `missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY` means libcrypto is missing.