# CMake find_library nvEncodeAPI.dll

Tags: c++, cmake, nvenc

I have Windows 7 64bit, CMake 3.8.1, NVidia Cuda 8.0, NVidia Video Codec SDK 7.1.9.

I have this file: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvEncodeAPI.dll`

I have this CMake module: `D:\projects\git\myProject\CMakeModules\FindNVenc.cmake` as follows...

Outline (of relevant part):

- Printing variables (sometimes environment variables after an `ENV` word)
- Printing `find_library` command
- Executing `find_library` command
- Printing `NVenc_LIBRARY` variable

Contents as-is (of relevant part):

```
message(STATUS "NVenc_ROOT: ${NVenc_ROOT} ENV $ENV{NVenc_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "NVenc_INCLUDE_DIR: ${NVenc_INCLUDE_DIR} ENV $ENV{NVenc_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR: ${NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR} ENV $ENV{NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR}")
message(STATUS "NVenc_LIBRARY_NAME: ${NVenc_LIBRARY_NAME}")
message(STATUS "find_library(NVenc_LIBRARY NAMES ${NVenc_LIBRARY_NAME} PATHS ${NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR} $ENV{NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR} ${NVenc_ROOT} $ENV{NVenc_ROOT} PATH_SUFFIXES lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)")
find_library(NVenc_LIBRARY NAMES ${NVenc_LIBRARY_NAME}
  PATHS ${NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR} $ENV{NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR} ${NVenc_ROOT} $ENV{NVenc_ROOT}
  PATH_SUFFIXES lib
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message(STATUS "NVenc_LIBRARY: ${NVenc_LIBRARY}")
```

The output is

```
-- NVenc_ROOT:  ENV D:\projects\git\libs
-- NVenc_INCLUDE_DIR: D:/projects/git/libs ENV
-- NVenc_LIBRARY_DIR:  ENV C:\Windows\SysWOW64
-- NVenc_LIBRARY_NAME: nvEncodeAPI
-- find_library(NVenc_LIBRARY nvEncodeAPI PATHS  C:\Windows\SysWOW64  D:\projects\git\libs PATH_SUFFIXES lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
-- NVenc_LIBRARY: NVenc_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

Which means that the `find_library` command did not find the file I have. This CMake module is working perfectly on Linux. (Worked until I started to alter it on Windows. Now I really don't know, but I think it still should work. Will fix If I broke it.)

Do I have a typo somewhere? Is there something that I don't get about `find_library`?

Comment: I have no idea if this could be the problem but shouldn't you use backslashes here since it's windows `-- NVenc_INCLUDE_DIR: D:/projects/git/libs ENV` ?

Comment: I tried forward and backward slashes at places. Did not change anything in any direction.

Comment: Try using find_library( ... HINTS <paths> )

Comment: Which generator do you use? If Visual Studio, it wants `.lib` file (it cannot link using `.dll`).

Comment: Yes. Visual Studio. What do you mean by wants? I don't have .lib, I will never have. Is it really impossible at all to use .h with .dll? Or I just have to use other ways with CMake?

Comment: Answer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856445/cmake-find-sqlite3-library-on-windows) also tells that for Visual Studio `find_library` looks for `.lib`. Not sure whether it is actually applied to 64-bit Windows, but you may check content of `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` variable. You may try to create `.lib` from `.dll` by following [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you give me reference for the "it cannot link using .dll"?

Comment: From the CMake [mailing discussion](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/FindLibrary-only-looks-for-lib-under-Windows-tp5532822p5535193.html): `In VS linking to the .lib is necessary even though the executable code is in the .dlls`. See also [Linking an Executable to a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx) in MSDN.